# How to Implement Multibuy discount in Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

One of the **categories** I'm selling are **Greeting Cards**. I want to offer a `Buy 4 for £10` promotion, applicable multiple times within a single shop (i.e. if someone buys multiples of 4)...

But all I see is the ability to discount `4 of the same card design`. I have also considered setting a price tier, but again, this only applies to the same design.

Any ideas?

Thanks for any help I get from you guys on this: I'm losing my mind..!

MisterGee

Comment: You can use promotion cart rules, see: http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-shopping-cart.html